# Which is the best way to retrieve data first from a cache then from a network call in RxJava ?(concat concatEager,merge)

Tags: android, rx-java2

For the first time I want to retrieve data from server cache it and next times show data on UI from local storage and request from server and update local storage and UI as

I have tried 
`(getCachedData()).concatWith(getRemoteData())`
getCachedData returns Single

````
   return apiSeResource.getData()
       .doAfterSuccess { response ->

           saveData(response.body())

       }
       }
       .onErrorReturn {
         return@onErrorReturn emptyList()
       }
 }```

The problem with `concat` is that the subsequent observable doesn't even start until the first Observable completes. That can be a problem. We want all observables to start simultaneously but produce the results in a way we expect.
I can use `concatEager` : It starts both observables but buffers the result from the latter one until the former Observable finishes.
Sometimes though, I just want to start showing the results immediately.
I don't necessarily want to "wait" on any Observable. In these situations, we could use the `merge` operator.
However the problem with merge is: if for some strange reason an item is emitted by the cache or slower observable after the newer/fresher observable, it will overwrite the newer content. 

So none of mentioned above solution is not proper ,what is your solution?
````

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 data sources one local data source and one remote and use the flatMap for  running the Obervables. You can publish the data from the cache and when u get data from remote save data to cache and publish.

Or you can also try Observable.merge(dataRequestOne, dataRequestTwo) . run both the Observables on different threads

Comment: But with merge   if for some strange reason an item is emitted by the cache or slower observable after the newer/fresher observable, it will overwrite the newer content.